# Read data from Firebase and hide a class

Tags: jquery, firebase

I have a Firebase database with users in it with the following data:

name: `Some Name`
email: `some@email.com`
tier: `standard` or `premium`

I'd like to hide the class `".premium-feature"` when the the Firebase data for 'tier' reads `standard`. If the data for 'tier' reads as anything else, I'll need to show `".premium-feature"`. Here's as far as I've gotten:

```
du.populateAccountFields = function() {
    var usr = new Firebase(firebase_url + "/users/" + user_uid);
    // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
    usr.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        user = snapshot.val();

        // inject tier data into an input
        $("#acct_tier").val(user.tier);
}
```

Any help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't completely understand the question. However, to hide a class use $('.theclass').hide(). Is that what you are asking? You may consider explaining a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
du.populateAccountFields = function() {
    var usr = new Firebase(firebase_url + "/users/" + user_uid);
    // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
    usr.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        user = snapshot.val();

        // inject tier data into an input
        $("#acct_tier").val(user.tier);
        var $premiumFeature = $('.premium-feature');
        if (user.tier === 'standard') {
           $premiumFeature.hide();
        } else {
           $premiumFeature.show();
        }
}
```

Comment: thank you, that's looking like what I need. I'll give a try and report back.

Comment: @user1661677 this seems like a valid answer. I'm glad you found it.